# Error starting Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

I am getting following error while starting elasticsearch-1.4.1. Can anyone please help me in resolving this.

[2017-07-16 09:12:12,649][ERROR][plugins                  ] [atom-es] cannot start plugin due to incorrect Lucene version: plugin [4.10.4], node [4.10.2].
[2017-07-16 09:12:12,650][WARN ][plugins                  ] [atom-es] failed to load plugin from [jar:file:/Users/atom/asanoujam/elasticsearch-1.4.1/plugins/analysis-icu/elasticsearch-analysis-icu-2.4.3.jar!/es-plugin.properties]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.plugin.analysis.icu.AnalysisICUPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:531)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginsFromClasspath(PluginsService.java:406)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:115)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Plugin is incompatible with the current node
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:524)
    ... 7 more
[2017-07-16 09:12:12,809][ERROR][plugins                  ] [atom-es] cannot start plugin due to incorrect Lucene version: plugin [4.10.4], node [4.10.2].
[2017-07-16 09:12:12,809][WARN ][plugins                  ] [atom-es] failed to load plugin from [jar:file:/Users/atom/asanoujam/elasticsearch-1.4.1/plugins/analysis-kuromoji/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji-2.7.0.jar!/es-plugin.properties]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.plugin.analysis.kuromoji.AnalysisKuromojiPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:531)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginsFromClasspath(PluginsService.java:406)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:115)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Plugin is incompatible with the current node
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:524)
    ... 7 more
[2017-07-16 09:12:12,970][ERROR][plugins                  ] [atom-es] cannot start plugin due to incorrect Lucene version: plugin [4.10.4], node [4.10.2].
[2017-07-16 09:12:12,971][WARN ][plugins                  ] [atom-es] failed to load plugin from [jar:file:/Users/atom/asanoujam/elasticsearch-1.4.1/plugins/analysis-smartcn/elasticsearch-analysis-smartcn-2.7.0.jar!/es-plugin.properties]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.plugin.analysis.smartcn.AnalysisSmartChinesePlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:531)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginsFromClasspath(PluginsService.java:406)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:115)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Plugin is incompatible with the current node
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:524)
    ... 7 more
[2017-07-16 09:12:20,141][INFO ][plugins                  ] [atom-es] loaded [lang-mvel, cloud-aws, es-reporting-plugin, clustering-carrot2, analysis-kuromoji-neologd, analysis-vietnamese], sites [carrot2, head]
[2017-07-16 09:12:54,699][INFO ][org.codelibs.elasticsearch.kuromoji.neologd.index.analysis.KuromojiDictionarySyncRunnable] Kuromoji Neologd dictionary sync triggered
[2017-07-16 09:12:56,326][INFO ][com.spr.elasticsearch.plugin.LookupScriptFactory] Created LookupScriptFactory with cache size of [ 100000 ] and timeout of [ 120 ]
{1.4.1}: Initialization Failed ...
- NoClassDefFoundError[org/apache/http/nio/entity/NStringEntity]
    ClassNotFoundException[org.apache.http.nio.entity.NStringEntity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those plugins are not compatible with Elasticsearch 1.4.1. You have to downgrade your plugins to use in ES 1.4.1. For ElasticSearch 1.4.1 you need to install following versions of the plugins

**elasticsearch-analysis-icu -> Version 2.4.1 for ES 1.4.1 (But you are trying to use 2.4.3)**

**elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji -> Version 2.4.1 for ES 1.4.1 (But you are trying to use 2.7.0)**

**elasticsearch-analysis-smartcn -> Version 2.4.2 for ES 1.4.1 (But you are trying to use 2.7.0)**

Comment: May be some of your dependency not resolved. Look at [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/noclassdeffounderror-httpasyncresponseconsumer/64231/2)

Comment: But I am starting this from terminal. How can this be a dependency issue ?

Comment: So then try to fresh download ES and run. Then install correct version of plugins.